# UIPasteboard to copy outside the app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipasteboard

I am trying to write a function to copy text from app. this text should be available outside the app in the clipboard, like when writing messages, web browser search fields.

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];    
NSString     *text       = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
[pasteboard setString:text];
NSLog(@"Value of myString = %@", pasteboard.string);
```

the value gets copied properly , but could not be used outside the app. I have tested things on simulator. How could I make the values available in the main clipboard also outside the app? Thanks

Comment: But you're using 2 different pasteboards. You need to use the same pasteboard to transfer the data. Generally `generalPasteboard` should be used.

Comment: @Wain I have updated the code to use generalPasteboard, but still it does not copy outside the app. thanks

Comment: The code looks fine, assuming the `NSLog` shows the proper value, your problem is likely elsewhere. Are you setting the pasteboard's string property again later? Also, setting the persistent value on the generalPasteboard is not needed since it's persistent already.

Comment: @MarcusAdams While testing in simulator when i try to do edit->paste in safari browser -> it shows some other value -> like some text i copied elsewhere earlier, not the one saved within the app. Thanks

Comment: If it contains text from earlier, you're probably not updating it. Put in a break point and ensure your code is being called. Good luck.

Comment: @MarcusAdams - the code worked perfectly when tested on device. The simulator clipboard was not getting updated when testing on it. Anyways my issue is solved now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. The code works perfectly when tested on device. In simulators somehow the clipboard functionality conflicts with the os clipboard.